# Listen to hardware button click event in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

As a simple test I'm trying to have a broadcastReceiver that will notify the user with a Toast message that an hardware button was clicked in android.

I've created a receiver tag in my manifest file with a name .TestReceiver that listens to Action_CALL_BUTTON to be informed when the user clicks on the green SEND button:

```
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>             
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>            
</receiver>
```

Next, I created the TestReceiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver and creates a Toast.
When I click on the call button I don't see the Toast message but I tested it on an activity and it shows.
What am I missing here?

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are some reasons why any `BroadcastReceiver` might fail to receive:

1. In your specific case, `ACTION_CALL_BUTTON` isn't a broadcast `Intent` action. It is an activity `Intent` action, which will not be intercepted by `BroadcastReceivers`. You can tell this via the "Activity Action" statement in the [documentation for this particular action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL_BUTTON).
2. The broadcast `Intent` might not be eligible for manifest-registered receivers. `ACTION_BATTERY_STATUS` is one such action. These can only be received by receivers registered in Java via `registerReceiver()`. Unfortunately, which follow this rule are only sporadically documented.
3. You may need a special permission to receive an `Intent`. For example, `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` only works if you hold the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission. These are usually mentioned in the documentation for that action.

Answer (score 0):

So I can register to the `ACTION_CALL_BUTTON` using `registerReceiver()` ?
I didn't see any permission required for that.

Comment: As I wrote: "In your specific case, ACTION_CALL_BUTTON isn't a broadcast Intent action. It is an activity Intent action, which will not be intercepted by BroadcastReceivers. You can tell this via the "Activity Action" statement in the documentation for this particular action."

Comment: So are you saying this is impossible? I'd like to write a service that receives this action - not an activity.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can follow this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm).you can see a tutorial of custom Intent to call Broadcast intent by clicking on button

This is Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT">
  </action>
  </intent-filter>
```

this is a Broadcast Receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Declare this method in Main Activity

```
public void broadcastIntent(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

and finally Your Button

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/broadcast_intent"
  android:onClick="broadcastIntent"/>
```

Comment: Your answer is not according to question. He is talking about hardware button

Answer (score -1):

You can use **onKeyDown()** method

method :-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
           // Your Task on hard menu click
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
          // Your Task on hard back click
             break;

            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```